# Npcs talk using /say

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Ok, so I've searched the web *everywhere* for this. ***EVERYWHERE***.
I'm in my creative world on an Apple iPad in Minecraft-PE trying to make a map. When I do `/say` in a command block for example:

```
/say Hello Wary traveler!
```

it says:

```
[!] Hello Wary traveler!
```

I've searched far and wide how to change that `[!]` into a name! I've tried renaming the command block. No luck. I've tried:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"[DizzyKitty] Hi
```

Says there's an error that I can never seem to fix. I tried looking it up on youtube and websites and I'm getting nowhere. Please help. I don't know if anyone knows the answer to my question, but if you do I would greatly aprrieate if you could help me! D;

Comment: Can you post the tellraw command you used?

Comment: /tellraw @a {"text":"[DizzyKitty] Hi
That's what was suggested to me. I don't know much about commands and I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a Java Edition command in Bedrock Edition.

Try `/tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"[DizzyKitty] Hi"}]}`.

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Ah, you're in bedrock. My mistake, I'll edit my answer @DizzyKitty.

Comment: It works perfectly now! thank you!

Comment: @DizzyKitty You can indicate that this answer solved your question by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons.